# CSS file is not found on localhost

Tags: css, node.js, express

I have a nodeJs app and I am using expressJs framework, I am trying to run:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

But I am getting this error:

> CSS file is not found on localhost

Comment: Try this: `app.use(express.static('public'))`

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));` 
This is creating a virtual path to itself. You should use this approach when you want to name it something else. For example, let's say you want to use `/assets` in the path, you'd state: `app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));`
But since you have the an actual folder named `public`, you can just write:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```